# Is there a free date/time entry spin-wheel control for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, controls, datepicker, spinner

Not sure what this control is actually "called", but I'm looking for a free version of one of these for Silverlight:

[image]

Does anyone know of something like this?

Comment: You can create one relatively easily if you can't find one.  Are you doing a touch based or mouse based control?

Comment: Mouse-based. Was looking rather than creating due to time constraints.

Comment: I see.  I looked and I couldn't find any (good) free controls. Unfortunately, it looks like you'll need to bake some custom code :( I don't have blend installed or I'd play for a bit and see what I could come up with.  It sounds like a very useful control that doesn't have a good free option.

Comment: Yeah. The standard control's not bad, but it has that modal aspect to it (e.g. click the header to switch "resolutions".

Comment: i think this type of date pickers is only good for touch devices, that's a lot of mouse clicks/wheel scrolling if you wanna select a date.

Comment: Well, this is opinion, but moving a scroll-wheel is roughly equivalent to flicking your finger up/down. But you still may have a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight toolkit has a DatePicker and a TimePicker control. http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: I like that the weekday name is under the number of the month. Handy.